# CGI errors when hosting on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core

I have a website that runs fine on my local IISExpress but when I upload it to Azure it is tediously slow and often returns an error: `The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process`

In project.json I have (amongst others) these dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
```

and these commands:

```
"commands": {
  "web": "MyApp",
},
```

My hosting.json file has:

```
{
  "server": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
}
```

And my Startup.cs has:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var application = new WebApplicationBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(WebApplicationConfiguration.GetDefault(args))
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        application.Run();
    }

    //etc...
```

Should I be using Kestrel or not? I'm not targeting any non-Windows platforms so it's just IISExpress and Azure I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade from the free/shared to a B1 instance. Apparently the packages during deployment are too big for the free/shared setups.